# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Commit in wrong place?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a shell of my stored procedure with the necessary parts not omitted:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure --name of sproc
    --declare sproc params
AS
BEGIN
  SET XACT_ABORT ON
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --declare a few vars

      --declare some table variables

            --do some work
            IF (--some condition here)
      BEGIN
        --actually do the work
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                SET @error = 'some value cannot be NULL'
                RAISERROR(@error, 16, 1)
                RETURN @error
            END
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT @error   = ERROR_NUMBER()
             , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
             , @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
             , @state = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR(@message, @severity, @state)
        RETURN @error
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

I am getting a deadlock error (which is not the subject of this post) in the "--actually do some work" section, and then the "Transaction count..." error is thrown.

Is my COMMIT in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Begin Transaction` above the `Begin Try`.  If the try fails and jumps to the catch, everything initialized in the try falls out of scope.  Beginning the transaction outside the scope of the try/catch makes it available to both the try and the catch block.

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense,